# Glade: Object has unrecognized type GtkStack

Tags: gtk, glade

I get the following problem in Glade:

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

The app was originally made with GTK+ 3.20, but in my Ubuntu 16.04, I only have GTK+ 3.18.

Any sugesstions to fix this?

Comment: upgrade your Gtk framework or install the latest ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the GTK+ version of the Glade file. [`GtkStack` was introduced in GTK+ 3.10](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html#GtkStack.description), so it will work with GTK+ 3.18. Most likely the version in the Glade file was set to 3.20, but you may set it to a lower value if you don't use newer APIs.

This is an old screenshot, but you get the point, you need to set an older toolkit version:

[image]

**Note:** My answer assumes that the application can run with older GTK+. If this is not the case, then you need to upgrade your GTK+ libriaries, or backport the application to GTK+ 3.18.